# Pattern matching not working on different version of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.0

I am trying to match a string pattern with my regex `'^\\d[0-9]*\/\d[0-9]*\/\d[0-9]*'` while fetching data from query. It is working fine on PostgreSQL version 9.5.4 but not working with version 9.0.4 which is my production server.

What amendments do I need to do in regex to make it compatible with PostgreSQL version 9.0.4?

Query:

```
Select * from table where column_name ~ '^\d[0-9]*\/\d[0-9]*\/\d[0-9]*'
```

I tried `E'^\\d[0-9]*\/\d[0-9]*\/\d[0-9]*'` as suggested in postgres doc (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) but its not working.

Comment: Postgres 9.0 is no longer supported. And 9.0.4 is missing **4 years** of bugfixes. You should at least upgrade to 9.0.23 which includes many bugfixes for regular expressions.

Comment: You don't need to escape forward slashes `/` (neither in escaped literals, nor in pattern matching). Also, `\d` is `[0-9]`. If I get this right, you want `'^\d+/\d+/\d+'` or in escaped literal: `E'^\\d+/\\d+/\\d+'`

Comment: Thanks pozs "E'^\\d+/\\d+/\\d+'" it worked for me. :-)  and ya i missed that \d and [0-9] is same.